# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable with list of floats

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have a list of floats in1 and I want to do two things: 1) convert that list of 1024 float items to dB values and 2) compare that list to a threshold value. I attempt to do this in the code shown below.

> ```
>         in1=islice(in0, 1024)    #1024 values are taken from the variable in0 and stored in in1
>     #Each item in the list of 1024 elements in in1 is converted to dB and then compared to a threshold 
>     for i in in1:
>             c = math.log10(i/1024)  #converts 1024 values stored in in1 to dB and stores them in c      
>             for i in c:
>          if i > 70:    #checks if any of the values stored in c are greater than a threshold value            
>               print "A signal is present"
>          else:
>               print "No signal is present"        
>         self.seen = 0
>     self.consume_each(in0.shape[0]) #consume everything you've account for
>                                 # tell system to move on to next samples
>     return 0        ##return 0 samples generated
>                     ## as the block doesn't have an output stream
> ```

What I'm assuming is that "c" contains a list of 1024 items converted to some value using the log10() method. I want to compare this list to a threshold. I've tried c.all() and c.any() and I received an attribute error, so I tried the approach above using "for i in c" and received the following error

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I want to find out if any of the values contained in "c" are greater than the threshold. Is there a better way of doing this??

Comment: c = math.log10(i/1024) is a float object. You cannot iterate over this object.

Comment: your indents are messed up

Answer (score 1):

When you're looping over in1 (which is a list of floats I assume) using

```
    for i in in1:
```

each element i is a single float element.
So, c is also a single float (c = math.log10(i/1024)).
That is why you cannot iterate over float using:

```
for i in c:
```

What might solve your problem is:

```
    #Each item in the list of 1024 elements in in1 is converted to dB and then compared to a threshold 
for i in map(lambda x: math.log10(float(x)/1024), in1):
     if i > 70:    #checks if any of the values stored in c are greater than a threshold value            
          print "A signal is present"
     else:
          print "No signal is present"        
    self.seen = 0
self.consume_each(in0.shape[0]) #consume everything you've account for
                            # tell system to move on to next samples
return 0        ##return 0 samples generated
                ## as the block doesn't have an output stream
```

The expression map(lambda x: math.log10(float(x)/1024), in1) converts the values into db. We're then iterating over the values already converted.

Edit:
You can do it all at once with map using the following code:

```
def check_signal(value):
    if value > 70:
        print "A signal is present"
    else:
        print "No signal present"
    self.seen = 0
in1_db = map(lambda x: math.log10(float(x)/1024), in1)
map(check_signal, in1_db)
self.consume_each(in0.shape[0]) #consume everything you've account for
                        # tell system to move on to next samples
return 0        ##return 0 samples generated
```

Comment: Just for clarity, each element would be converted to dB and then compared to the threshold?? Is there anyway of converting the list of elements to dB all at once and then comparing all of them to the threshold, rather than doing it element by element? If possible, I would prefer doing it that way.

Comment: Edited answer in response of the comment.